# Android Timer getting error

Tags: android, synchronization, timertask

Hi guys i have one toggle button i want to invoke the method on separately on state and off state. i can use the timer for each click but i can get the thread error any one help Other suitable method.Here i attached the sample code:

```
toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean on = ((ToggleButton) toggle).isChecked();
            if (on) {
                timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0l, 1000*60);  
            } else {
                timer1.schedule (hourlyTask1, 0l, 1000*60);   
        }
    });
```

And the implemented method is given below:

```
TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        // your code here...
            ConnectivityManager cn=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()==true ){
                Log.d("Network", "Avalilable");
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
                socket.connect(socketAddress, timeout);
                //Log.d("Enable", "yes");
                socket.close();
                save();
                //dbAdapter.deleteentry();
                Log.d("Enable", "yes");
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Socket Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Socket", e.toString());
            }
            }
            else{
                Log.d("Network", "UnAvalilable");
                while(nf!=null){
                    timer2.schedule (hourlyTask2, 0l, 1000*60);
                }
           }
        }
};
```

#### Log Cat:

```
        05-29 18:47:07.228: W/dalvikvm(32247): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430ef140)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247): Process: com.example.poweranalyzer, PID: 32247
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247): java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:572)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:481)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at com.example.poweranalyzer.Home$6.onClick(Home.java:257)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
        05-29 18:47:07.228: E/AndroidRuntime(32247):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: simultaneously two thread running something like this....

Comment: That isn't enough information, you need to provide the exact stack trace.

Comment: this is okay for you

Answer (score 0):

update code with this,

```
 toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) toggle).isChecked();
        if (on) { timer.cancel(); timer= new Timer();
            timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0l, 1000*60);  
    } else { timer1.cancel(); timer1= new Timer();
            timer1.schedule (hourlyTask1, 0l, 1000*60);   
    }
});
```

Comment: if i close within toggle button i cant open the save(); method so  i can close this timer within save() method itself how can i give

Answer (score 0):

`TimerTask` indeed runs in another thread.
You can use a `Handler` and send a delayed message to it.

- Creating the Handler and overriding handleMessage:

  ```
  Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
          @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              super.handleMessage(msg);
              // your code
          }
  };
  ```
- Sending the delayed message:

  ```
  handler.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 1000*60);
  ```

Comment: All you need is in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

your logcat says

```
TimerTask is scheduled already
```

Try cancelling the other timer when you start one. because when toggle button is set on, timer is scheduled, off timer1 is scheduled. ON againe, it is trying to schedule the timer which is alreasy scheduled.

Comment: in my case i can invoke the method save(); after that method only it will be  cancel but i will give timer.cancel(); and also it will show same error